# How to mark input as dirty via HTML?

Tags: angularjs

I have an input and I would like to set the input as dirty right away:

```
<input ng-model="something">
```

I tried:

```
<input ng-model="something" class="ng-dirty">
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What is your purpose? Do you change something outside of angular?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpTen/216/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app="">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required/>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required</span><br></br>
   </form>
</div>
```

**script**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.userType = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, Angular does the determination if the field is dirty, not you. That being said, you can force it by calling $setDirty() on that element.

```
<form name='theFormName'>
    <input name='theElementName' type='text' />
</form>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.theFormName.theElementName.$setDirty();
```

You will find more information in the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController). This isn't something that you should be doing often, though.